# Swagger spring fox do not handle Response Model for List and arrays

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to expose an api with spring mvc and documenting it with swagger.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/entry/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieves all diary entries persisted in the database",produces = "application/json" ,responseContainer = "List", response = Entry.class)
public List<Entry> getDiaryEntries() {
    List<Entry> diaryEntries =new ArrayList<>();
    diaryEntries.add(new Entry());

    return  diaryEntries;
}
```

when I look at the swagger ui

[[image]

the array content looks *undefined* altho I specified responseContainer = "List", response = Entry.class.

I would expect something like

```
[{ "title" : "" , "text":"" } ]
```